# Vue.js losing data when clicking out of the input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input, methods

I'm using [Vuesax Framework](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/), I make inputs with v-for, this inputs have dynamic v-model and dynamic placeholder too and also dynamic array on v-for, but I have two cases, the first one it's when I have an array of an element, and the second on it's just when I have one element. I've used a functions that return the array or just the element depends according to other variables. Now if I set a value in one of the inputs, I lost this info when I click out. I tried to give the v-model, placeholder and the v-for directly the returned variable but I still have the problem 
The HTML

```
        <vs-input
        :v-model="uniteOrder(j)"
        class="w-100 mt-8"
        :label-placeholder="matiereName(j)"
        :key="j"
        v-for="j in matiereIdLength()" />
```

My methods

```
methods: {
    uniteOrder(j) {

      if (this.addOrEdit == 'add') {

        return this.unite_order[j-1]
      } else {

        return this.unite_order
      }
    },
    matiereName(j) {
      if (this.addOrEdit == 'add') {

        return this.matiere_name[j-1]
      } else {

        return  this.matiere_name;
      }
    },
    matiereIdLength() {

      if (this.addOrEdit == 'add') {

        return this.matiere_id.length
      } else {

        return this.matiere_id.toString().split()
      }
    },
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't simply treat one element as an array with one element?

Comment: @Alex the array of one element is just this.matiere_id.toString().split(), but the others returns are strings, and I've used this method because I can't use an array in v-bind. If it's possible please tell me how